# A confusion about same origin policy(sop) and csrf protection

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy, csrf-protection

I have a confusion about the Same Origin Policy(SOP).

For example, `http://bad.com/bad.html` with a `bad.js`, and `http://good.com/good.html` with a `good.js`. I open both urls in my chrome with two tabs(tab1, and tab2).

In the good.html(opened in tab2), there is a element `<input id="token-id" type='text' name='token' value='123abc'>`

Now the question is **if there is no SOP**, whether it's possible to read the element `input` value from bad.html(opened in tab1) with some code like `document.getElementById('token-id').value()` in `bad.js`.

Another question is **if the above question's answer is 'no'**, I can't understand this sentence in wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Security_Concerns.

> Regarding the sending of new transactions, even CSRF protections by the banking site have no effect, because the script can simply do the same as the user would do

As we can't get the csrf token. why it does't work. Server can figure the real post request by verify the csrf token.

Do I misunderstand the csrf protection or the SOP itself?

Thanks if anyone can help me figure out these confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding some things, the SOP says that if you open `http://bad.com/bad.html` and that page loads and executes `bad.js`, that javascript can make an AJAX request to `bad.com`, but any request pointing to `good.com` will be blocked unless `good.com` accepts it explicitly (by using CORS protocol).

The reason is that any request to any site may include the cookies that the browser has stored related to that site, so bad.com could use the session that you did not close on good.com to do something harmful.

So regarding your questions: No, a tab is not aware of other tabs unless they are related (parent - child), so a page cannot modify the behavior of another one. And the SOP ensures that a page cannot impersonate as another one

Comment: "any request pointing to good.com will be blocked" — Not true. Only complex requests will be blocked. Simple requests will go through but the response will be denied to JS.

Comment: @Pablo First of all, thank you very much. Does the related tabs means one tab is opened by other tab via `window.open` function?

Comment: @VincentQiu Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

> Now the question is if there is no SOP, whether it's possible to read the element input value from bad.html(opened in tab1) with some code like document.getElementById('token-id').value() in bad.js.

No — since there is no reference to the other tab.

If the tab being read from was opened via `window.open` from the tab doing the reading (instead of manually), then the token could be read.

Happily, the Same Origin Policy **does** exist, so we don't need to worry about that.

---

> Regarding the sending of new transactions, even CSRF protections by the banking site have no effect, because the script can simply do the same as the user would do

The CSRF token contains information only available to the browser and the friendly site.

Since the attacking site can't read the token, the attacking site can't construct a request that includes it. The friendly site can determine that the request constructed by the attacking site is untrustworthy because it doesn't include the token.

If the Same Origin Policy didn't exist, then the attacking site *could* read the token, which would render the token useless.

Since the Same Origin Policy does exist, that isn't a concern.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. So, there is only one situation that I open `http://good.com/good.html` by clicking a link in `http://bad.com`. Then the token will be read by `bad.js` in `http://bad.com`. without this situation, the token should be useful even there is no SOP. Does it right?